# how can use GDPR consent in the advertising networks such as AdMob, Vungle, Ironsource, and Applovin?

Tags: android, admob, applovin, vungle-ads, ironsource

The GDPR requires a legal basis for data processing. after using `com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library`
to show consent in the Android app, how can use GDPR consent in the advertising networks such as AdMob, Vungle, Ironsource, and Applovin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to forward consent to the **Google Mobile Ads SDK** you can use this code

```
extras.putString("npa", "1");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();
```

in the **IronSource** If the user has opted out of “sale” of personal information

`IronSource.setMetaData("do_not_sell","true");`

If “sale” of personal information is permitted:

`IronSource.setMetaData("do_not_sell","false");`

in the **Vungle**, the following sample code sets the consent status to OPTED_IN
`Vungle.updateConsentStatus(Vungle.Consent.OPTED_IN, "1.0.0");`

and this code sets the consent status to OPTED_OUT

`Vungle.updateConsentStatus(Vungle.Consent.OPTED_OUT, "1.0.0");`

**AppLovin** added the **setHasUserContent** and **setIsAgeRestrictedUser** methods. The following sample code shows how to pass consent information to the AppLovin SDK.

`AppLovinPrivacySettings.setHasUserConsent(true, context);`

if the user is known to be in an age-restricted category, you can also set the below flag to true.

`AppLovinPrivacySettings.setIsAgeRestrictedUser(true, context);`